# JavaScript / jQuery - Open current link in pop-up window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

```
<a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
```

How can I open this link in a pop-up window? And prevent the browser to block it

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There's "new windows" and there's "popups". Using `target=_blank` will open in a new window, except that modern browsers put new windows in new **tabs** by default. Which sounds like it isn't what you want.

For an actual popup you want `window.open()`, and be sure to include some specific width and height, otherwise some browsers will still put the new window in a new tab. Darin's example looks good to me.

As for popup blocking, the general approach that browsers take is that popups initiated by **user action** are allowed (such as clicking), while popups initiated spontaneously through script, such as this, are blocked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open("http://www.google.com/", "Google", "width=500,height=500");
</script>
```

However, ad blocking being an escalating war, you can never be sure that a popup will open. If your popup *is* blocked, the window.open call returns null. So I would modify Daren's example like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"
    onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Google', 'width=500,height=500')"
    target="_blank">
```

If the popup is blocked, onclick returns `true`, which follows the link they clicked by opening it in a new window or tab. It's a fallback, so at least the content is accessible (if not pretty).

Comment: I should also add, it's a good idea to have your popup content not be totally broken if it opens in a full-sized browser window, because of this fallback, and because the user could always right-click the link and "open in new tab or window" which circumvents the onClick handler altogether.

Answer (score 13):

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'windowName', 'width=1000, height=700, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable'); return false;">Link</a>
```

Comment: One interesting bug i have noticed according `window.open`. if the url starts with `http://...`, it doesn't work in ie ...

Answer (score 2):

This will open a new window.

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: If you are using XHTML Strict, the `target` attribute doesn't validate and you should attach an event (such as 'onclick') instead. If you are using an older doctype, you're fine with `target="_blank"`.

Comment: @Andrew - IMO that was an *absolutely* ridiculous decision on the W3C's part (deprecating `target`)...one that has been reversed in HTML5, in case anyone finds this later wondering.

Comment: I've not been following the HTML5 specs recently, but the [latest revisions on W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#linkTypes) says `target` is still "unnecessary. Omit it altogether."  I'm not defending this, but the idea is that HTML is supposed to be used for layout (defining the relationships between page data), CSS is for presentation and JS is for behaviour. And under this system, clicking on a link to open a window is a behaviour. That said, HTML5's CSS extensions are full of this kind of violation, so I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('#button2').live("click",function(e){    
  window.open("http://www.google.com", "yyyyy", "width=480,height=360,resizable=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,status=no");
return false;
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="button2" ><img src="images/online.png"></a><br/>Online
```

Comment: live has been deprecated in jquery 1.6 I believe, use .on("click", function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working properly

```
        <style>
        td,
th {
    border: 2px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);
    padding: 20px;
}

td {
    text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #eee;
}

th[scope="col"] {
    background-color: #696969;
    color: #fff;
}

th[scope="row"] {
    background-color: #d7d9f2;
}

caption {
    padding: 20px;
    caption-side: bottom;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

JS BELOW

```
</style>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Script below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>
```

Code

```
echo "<td><ul class='list-inline'>";      
           echo "<li><a href=# title=Increaseby".$d."%&nbsp;".$h."%&nbsp;".$k."% data-toggle=popover data-placement=top data-content=".$p4."&nbsp;".$p6."&nbsp;".$p8.">View Increase</a></li>";
           
            echo "</ul></td>";
```

Try This Hopefully it will resolve your issue

Answer (score -1):

You can try the code below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.open(location.href, "Google", "width=500,height=500");
</script>
```