# How do I get this button to popup the link?

Tags: javascript

When I click this button it loads the page onto my previous page. What can I do to make it popup on a new page or tab?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;height:100%;" onclick= "location.href='LINKLINKLINKLINK'">Verify</button>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use window.open instead - but also visit [help] to see why this is voted down and closed as off topic. HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript / jQuery - Open current link in pop-up window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219325/javascript-jquery-open-current-link-in-pop-up-window)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to open the required page as a popup. Try this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;height:100%;" onclick= "window.open('LINKLINKLINKLINK')">Verify</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Window.open is more accurate for your use. You could also add the target attribute to your link so it will open a new tab or window :

```
window.open("yourlink", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the target attribute it helps you open it in new page or this page and many more the below code can help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Open Link In New Tab</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google in New Tab</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```